# How to Parse Visio Files Using Python

Tags: python, binary, visio

I have used Apache POI to parse .pptx and visio files in Java.  I also know that Python has python-pptx for parsing powerpoints. But has anyone run across a really good library for parsing the binary associated with Visio files for Python? I see a lot of questions and answers for other languages, but not for Python.  Any helpful suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please try [vsdx](https://pypi.org/project/vsdx/) - A python library for processing .vsdx files

Comment: This library works with vsdx-documenst, not binary!